# How to get next/previous partition count using window function?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to get the `current_count`, `next_count`, and `previous_count` for `date.month` partitions with window functions:

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
SELECT location.city, date.month, date.year
     , COUNT(*) OVER W AS current_count, COUNT(*) OVER W2 AS 
count_next
FROM fact, crime, date, location 
WHERE fact.location_key = location.location_key and crime.crime_key = 
fact.crime_key and fact.date_key = date.date_key

WINDOW W AS (
        PARTITION BY location.city, date.year, date.month
        ORDER BY date.month
    ),

    W2 AS (
        PARTITION BY location.city, date.year, date.month
        ORDER BY date.month
        RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND FOLLOWING
    )
)

SELECT *
FROM tmp1 
GROUP BY city, year, month,current_count, count_next
```

However, the code above works for `current_count` only, the `count_next` shows the same result as the `current_count`.

How to show the count for next month and previous month? With window functions?

Comment: Postgres version, actual (minimal) table definitions, sample values and desired result would be instrumental for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Do the aggregation first. *Then* use the [`lead()` and `lag()` window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE). Looks like you were aiming for something like this:

```
SELECT *
     , lead(curr_count) OVER w AS next_count
     , lag(curr_count)  OVER w AS prev_count
FROM (
   SELECT l.city, d.year, d.month, count(*) AS curr_count
   FROM   fact     f
   JOIN   crime    c ON c.crime_key = f.crime_key    -- see below
   JOIN   date     d ON d.date_key = f.date_key
   JOIN   location l ON l.location_key = f.location_key
   GROUP  BY l.city, d.year, d.month
   ) sub
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY year, month)
ORDER  BY city, year, month;
```

You can use a CTE or a subquery (like I did) to apply the logic in two steps. May be easier to understand at first. But you can add window functions over aggregate functions in the same query level. See:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

So this is equivalent and shorter (probably same query plan / performance):

```
SELECT l.city, d.year, d.month
     , count(*)              AS curr_count
     , lead(count(*)) OVER w AS next_count
     , lag(count(*))  OVER w AS prev_count
FROM   fact     f
JOIN   crime    c USING (crime_key)    -- see below
JOIN   date     d USING (date_key)
JOIN   location l USING (location_key)
GROUP  BY l.city, d.year, d.month
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY l.city ORDER BY d.year, d.month);
```

Use equivalent [explicit join syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). Much easier to read.

The `USING` shorthand in the join clause of my second query is only legit if column names are unambiguous. Else stick to the explicit `ON` syntax in the first query.

Why join to table `crime`? Does the join eliminate or multiply rows? Else you can remove it completely.

Use [table aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) to keep the noise low.

You had `PARTITION BY location.city, date.year, date.month ORDER BY date.month`. But I suggest you really want `PARTITION BY city ORDER BY year, month` to make the query work across year boundaries?

It would probably be more efficient to use a single column of type `date` (4 bytes) instead of `year` and `month`. (But don't name it just "date".)

Note how I skipped `ORDER BY city, year, month` in the second query. You *normally* get rows sorted that way anyway due to the window definition, but there are no guarantees without explicit `ORDER BY`. And you did not specify that order is required. If so, you might want to be explicit about this and add `ORDER BY`.